# Linux: Which process is causing "device busy" when doing umount?

Tags: linux, shell, device, mount, umount

Linux: Which process is causing "device busy" when doing umount?

Comment: You will need to provide some more information. There could be a number of different answers....

Comment: what info do you need? what are the possible answers?

Comment: Reverting most recent edits.  First off, shell scripting is as much programming as .net, SQL queries or iphone development.  Secondly, removing the linux designation makes the question ambitious.  BSD, OSX, etc. have slightly different semantics, and Solaris, etc. even more so.

Comment: don't forget `NFS`! You need to stop all NFS export or mount points on the drive you want to `umount`. NFS does NOT show up on `lsof` or `fuser`... so it's very tricky!

Comment: Wouldn't this be on-topic at [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Look at the [lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) command (list open files) -- it can tell you which processes are holding what open.  Sometimes it's tricky but often something as simple as `sudo lsof | grep (your device name here)` could do it for you.

Comment: In my case, grepping the device name didn't show any result. However, grepping the path into which the device was actually mounted did; so finally, by killing that process I was able to umount the device successfully.

Comment: In my case the command didn't show anything. Exiting SSH client and logging in again did it.

Comment: You were probably inside that direction while trying to unmount it.

Comment: `lsof /mountpoint` instead of `lsof /mountpoint/`

Comment: [There's an advantage to using `lsof +f /dev/device` rather than the mountpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782183/5353461). See the same for kernel processes with anonymous inodes which may not show up even in that listing.

Answer (score 53):

Just in case... sometimes happens that you are calling umount from the terminal, and your current directory belongs to the mounted filesystem.

Comment: Got me too. You can recognise this if lsof lists the "bash" process (debian)

Comment: `fuser` catches current working directories like this I believe.

Comment: it happens in mount point which sub dirctory has been bind mount. such as /data mount in /dev/vdb1 and  /data/kubernetes/kubelet use by kubelet, which has some bind mount `tmpfs        /data/kubernetes/kubelet/pods/3959731f-4e0e-4d93-8930-f475cf6f877d/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-x6957`

Answer (score 31):

You should use the [fuser](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) command.

Eg. `fuser /dev/cdrom` will return the pid(s) of the process using `/dev/cdrom`.

If you are trying to unmount, you can kill theses process using the `-k` switch (see `man fuser`).

Comment: FYI `fuser` will sometimes show things that `lsof` does not and vice versus. so you can not do just one or the other!

Comment: Didn't work, but you gave me the idea to kill my media player, and that worked, so thanks for the idea ;-)

Answer (score 23):

Check for open loop devices mapped to a file on the filesystem with "losetup -a". They wont show up with either lsof or fuser.

Comment: Exactly! I had loop devices mounted onto .iso files on the partition in question.

The `umount -l /data` actually worked - the FS disappeared - but later unmounting `/dev/loop0` and `/dev/loop1` hanged for a while. But now is seems all right.

This answer is very important, because it helps people, who've known `lsof` and `fuser` for ages...

Comment: This was key for me.  in my case the docker devicemapper storage drive created `/dev/loop0 /dev/loop1` loop devices.  The only way I could get rid of them was listing devices using the `dmsetup ls`  then finding the suspect docker devicemapper device docker-253:0-4291588-pool.   `dmsetup remove docker-253:0-4291588-pool` got rid of it cleanly

Answer (score 18):

Also check `/etc/exports`.  If you are exporting paths within the mountpoint via NFS, it will give this error when trying to unmount and nothing will show up in `fuser` or `lsof`.

Comment: In our case it was our problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it show up? Is this because nfs, is partly in the kernel ?(in contrast to being completely userspace)

Answer (score 9):

```
lsof +f -- /mountpoint
```

(as lists the processes using files on the mount mounted at /mountpoint. Particularly useful for finding which process(es) are using a mounted USB stick or CD/DVD.

Comment: This helped me find a process whose current working directory prevented the AUTOCLEAR of a loop device mount. It wasn't listed in `fuser` or standard `lsof`.

Comment: Even better is to use `/dev/<device>` rather than `/mountpoint` as `/mountpoint` will disappear after an `umount -l`.

Answer (score 8):

lsof and fuser are indeed two ways to find the process that keeps a certain file open.
If you just want umount to succeed, you should investigate its -f and -l options.

Comment: I had this problem recently and neither fuser or lsof would show anything using the device, but umount -l allowed me to unmount it. At least, it appears to (-l means Lazy Unmount, Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.)

Answer (score 7):

#### Open files

Processes with open files are the usual culprits. Display them:

```
lsof +f -- <mountpoint or device>
```

There is an advantage to using  `/dev/<device>` rather than `/mountpoint`: a mountpoint will disappear after an `umount -l`, or it may be hidden by an overlaid mount.

`fuser` can also be used, but to my mind `lsof` has a more useful output. However `fuser` is useful when it comes to killing the processes causing your dramas so you can get on with your life.

List files on `<mountpoint>` (see caveat above):

```
fuser -vmM <mountpoint>
```

Interactively kill only processes with files open for writing:

```
fuser -vmMkiw <mountpoint>
```

After remounting read-only (`mount -o remount,ro <mountpoint>`), it is safe(r) to kill all remaining processes:

```
fuser -vmMk <mountpoint>
```

#### Mountpoints

The culprit can be the kernel itself. Another filesystem mounted on the filesystem you are trying to `umount` will cause grief. Check with:

```
mount | grep <mountpoint>/
```

For loopback mounts, also check the output of:

```
losetup -la
```

#### Anonymous inodes (Linux)

[Anonymous inodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4508998/5353461) can be created by:

- Temporary files (`open` with `O_TMPFILE`)
- [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watches
- [eventfd]
- [eventpoll]
- [timerfd]

These are the most elusive type of pokemon, and appear in `lsof`'s `TYPE` column as `a_inode` (which is undocumented in the  [`lsof` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)).

They won't appear in `lsof +f -- /dev/<device>`, so you'll need to:

```
lsof | grep a_inode
```

For killing processes holding anonymous inodes, see: [List current inotify watches (pathname, PID)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386877/143394).

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly why the "fuser -m /mount/point" exists.

BTW, I don't think "fuser" or "lsof" will indicate when a resource is held by kernel module, although I don't usually have that issue..

Comment: but this is exactly the issue I seem to have. how does one debug this?

Answer (score 4):

If you still can not unmount or remount your device after stopping all services and processes with open files, then there may be a swap file or swap partition keeping your device busy. This will not show up with `fuser` or `lsof`. Turn off swapping with:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

You could check beforehand and show a summary of any swap partitions or swap files with:

```
swapon -s
```

or:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

As an alternative to using the command `sudo swapoff -a`, you might also be able to disable the swap by stopping a service or *systemd* unit. For example:

```
sudo systemctl stop dphys-swapfile
```

or:

```
sudo systemctl stop var-swap.swap
```

In my case, turning off swap was necessary, in addition to stopping any services and processes with files open for writing, so that I could remount my root partition as read only in order to run `fsck` on my root partition without rebooting. This was necessary on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 3):

lsof and fuser didn't give me anything either.

After a process of renaming all possible directories to .old and rebooting the system every time after I made changes I found one particular directory (relating to postfix) that was responsible.

It turned out that I had once made a symlink from /var/spool/postfix to /disk2/pers/mail/postfix/varspool in order to minimise disk writes on an SDCARD-based root filesystem (Sheeva Plug).

With this symlink, even after stopping the postfix and dovecot services (both ps aux as well as netstat -tuanp didn't show anything related) I was not able to unmount /disk2/pers.

When I removed the symlink and updated the postfix and dovecot config files to point directly to the new dirs on /disk2/pers/ I was able to successfully stop the services and unmount the directory.

Next time I will look more closely at the output of:

```
ls -lR /var | grep ^l | grep disk2
```

The above command will recursively list all symbolic links in a directory tree (here starting at /var) and filter out those names that point to a specific target mount point (here disk2).

Comment: I am actually looking for symbolic links (the ^l in my command), your command might be faster but does not have the same effect.

Comment: D'oh... that's because I typoed the command.  It should be `find /var -lname *disk2*`

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems mounted on the filesystem you're trying to unmount can cause the `target is busy` error in addition to any files that are in use. (For example when you `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/yourmount/dev` in order to use `chroot` there.)

To find which file systems are mounted on the filesystem run the following:

`mount | grep '/mnt/yourmount'`

To find which files are in use the advice already suggested by others here:

`lsof | grep '/mnt/yourmount'`