# What is an anonymous inode in Linux?

Tags: linux, epoll, inode

I made a google search about "anonymous inode" and it seems it's related to epoll ... but what actually is it?

Comment: See accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At least in some contexts, an anonymous inode is an inode without an attached directory entry.  The easiest way to create such an inode is as such:

```
int fd = open( "/tmp/file", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666 );
unlink( "/tmp/file" );
// Note that the descriptor fd now points to an inode that has no filesystem entry; you
// can still write to it, fstat() it, etc. but you can't find it in the filesystem.
```

Comment: In short, an anonymous inode is an inode which is not representing a file but a memory block?

Comment: No, it is data on disk, but that data doesn't have an entry in the filesystem anymore from which it can be opened -- you can only use the data until the last file descriptor open on it closes.  One situation in which you would want this is when you need a temporary file that you don't want anyone to be able to open; many of the uses of the mktemp() call in UNIX are actually cases where you don't want other processes to be able to open the file, you just need a temporary file for some reason or another.

Comment: For this example you almost surely want to add `O_EXCL` and make the mode `0600` rather than `0666`... As it is there are at least two major potential vulnerabilities (symlink vuln and race condition window where another user could open the file if your `umask` isn't restrictive enough).

Comment: Is there any way to re-link the directory entry?

Comment: Nope, such a file cannot be re-linked.

Comment: Things like `timerfd` also use anonymous inodes.

Answer (score 11):

**`open` with `O_TMPFILE`**

This would be a good definition of anonymous inode: it creates an inode inside a given directory without any name, which does not appear at all with `ls`.

Then when you close the descriptor the file is deleted.

It was added in Linux 3.11.

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[]  = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    char buf2[]  = { 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' };
    int f, ret;
    size_t off;

    /* write */
    f = open(".", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ret = write(f, buf, sizeof(buf));

    /* Interactivelly check if anything changed on directory. It hasn't. */
    /*puts("hit enter to continue");*/
    /*getchar();*/

    /* read */
    lseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    off = 0;
    while ((ret = read(f, buf2 + off, sizeof(buf) - off))) {
        off += ret;
    }
    close(f);
    assert(!memcmp(buf, buf2, sizeof(buf)));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/fd6062a38ce6d6a49772666a813fb9d7ccd10dac/userland/linux/open_o_tmpfile.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -o main.out -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  main.c
./main.out
```

This is therefore essentially the optimal way of implementing temporary files: [How to create a temporary text file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022487/how-to-create-a-temporary-text-file-in-c/26224447#26224447) as it can:

- always immediately find a free name without us having to loop over filenames (no name is needed!)
- and has automatic deletion

Compare that to a more manual method for directories as the one shown at: [How to create a temporary directory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c/58454949#58454949)

Tested in Ubuntu 17.04, Linux 4.10, glibc 2.24.

**How `O_TMPFILE` looks like in `/proc/PID/fd`**

We can examine it quickly with:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int f = open(".", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    struct stat s;
    fstat(f, &s);
    printf("pid %jd\n", (intmax_t)getpid());
    printf("inode %jd\n", (intmax_t)s.st_ino);
    getchar();
}
```

then for a sample output:

```
pid 15952     
inode 44698689
```

we do:

```
ls -l /proc/15952/fd
```

and that contains:

```
3 -> '/home/ciro/test/#44698689 (deleted)'
```

which shows us how to find temporary files for a given process and see their `inode` and inode parent directory.

**`anon_inode_getfd` Linux kernel function**

If you are dealing with kernel modules, this is a likely definition.

You call it like:

```
fd = anon_inode_getfd("random", &fops_anon, NULL, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
```

and return `fd` to user, e.g. from an `ioctl`.

Now the user has an `fd` with associated arbitrary `file_operations` and `inode`, and when that `fd` is closed, everything is freed.

This method is useful e.g. if you want to have multiple `read` syscalls, but don't want to create multiple device files, which further pollutes `/dev`: you just create extra `ioctl`s instead.

Minimal runnable example with QEMU Buildroot:

- https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/de6c179fc0cf122789f0fe85cc69b847a1f4fe9c/kernel_module/anonymous_inode.c
- https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/de6c179fc0cf122789f0fe85cc69b847a1f4fe9c/rootfs_overlay/anonymous_inode.sh

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h> /* copy_from_user, copy_to_user */
#include <linux/anon_inodes.h>
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h> /* EFAULT */
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* min */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h> /* printk */

#include "anonymous_inode.h"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct dentry *dir;

static ssize_t read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    char kbuf[1024];
    size_t ret;

    ret = snprintf(kbuf, sizeof(kbuf), "%llu", (unsigned long long)jiffies);
    if (copy_to_user(buf, kbuf, ret)) {
        ret = -EFAULT;
    }
    return ret;
}

static const struct file_operations fops_anon = {
    .read = read,
};

static long unlocked_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long argp)
{
    int fd;

    switch (cmd) {
        case LKMC_ANONYMOUS_INODE_GET_FD:
            fd = anon_inode_getfd(
                "random",
                &fops_anon,
                NULL,
                O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC
            );
            if (copy_to_user((void __user *)argp, &fd, sizeof(fd))) {
                return -EFAULT;
            }
        break;
        default:
            return -EINVAL;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations fops_ioctl = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = unlocked_ioctl
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    dir = debugfs_create_dir("lkmc_anonymous_inode", 0);
    debugfs_create_file("f", 0, dir, NULL, &fops_ioctl);
    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    debugfs_remove_recursive(dir);
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
```

**`anon_inode` in /proc/PID/fd**

These are pipes and sockets, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463548/what-is-anon-inode-in-the-output-of-ls-l